# JTidy output in String instead of Document?

Tags: java, jtidy

I am trying to convert an HTML string to an XHTML string using JTidy to then parse with XMLWorkerHelper. How do I get the output from Tidy in String instead of Document please?

My code is:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
                
org.w3c.dom.Document ppout = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(activityDtl.getPPDescription().toString().getBytes()), null);
System.out.println("ppout: " + ppout);
              
p6.add(new Chunk("Description:   ", smallBold));
ElementList list1 = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(ppout, null);

for (Element element : list1) {
    p6.add(element);
    preface6.add(p6);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream 
    (activityDtl.getPPDescription().getBytes("UTF-8"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
                
tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, baos);
String ppDescription = baos.toString();
              
p6.add(new Chunk("Description:   ", smallBold));
ElementList list1 = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(ppDescription, null);
for (Element element : list1) {
    p6.add(element);
}
preface6.add(p6);
```